# what is the disadvatage with more markup in your code?

Tags: html

I read somewhere about a tutorial on how to make a dropcap

here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<style>
h1, h2, h3, h4, p, ul, li, address, blockquote {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    width: 720px;

    font: 90%/1.6 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

    padding: 25px;
}

.dropcap p:first-of-type:first-letter {
    float: left;
    font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
    font-size: 4em;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    line-height: .7;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<section class="dropcap">

<p>You can use floats to create dropcaps as well. Simply float the first letter of the desired paragraph and set the margins of the float to control spacing. If you want to drop cap a range of letters, simply use a span tag around the letters you want to drop. You can use relative positioning or top margins to help position the cap relative to the paragraph. Because the construct for float elements is a little different in earlier versions of Internet Explorer, if you're targeting versions prior to IE 8 you may need to feed slightly different margin values through conditional comments to have consistent styling. Firefox does NOT allow the dropcap to calculate its own line-height, forcing it to inherit it from the parent paragraph. WebKit based browsers will. This means that in order to have dropcaps line up consistently in WebKit based browsers and Firefox, you'll need to apply a line-height equal to the height of the cap (start at around .8, although you'll need to experiment  with it based on the font you're using).</p>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

He said this is better than using a **span tag** then targeting the letter you want to dropcap

here is my question what is the disadvatage of more markup tags in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Well the obvious disadvantage of more markup in your code is that it is less readable, adds more bytes to the filesize and adds more variables to the code and thus more possible bugs.

The disadvantage of using a CSS style on the section element is that it is not as easy to target the letter that you want. Yes, if you are wanting to target the first letter, it's cake. But what if you wanted to target the seventh letter? IMO, span would be better in this case, but I have never ever ran into a use case for targeting the seventh letter of a paragraph with dropcase :p.